# Rename [scenekit-modelio]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

[The questions with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scenekit-modelio) are trying to refer to [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio).

Model I/O is not specifically for use with SceneKit. If the creator of the tag was trying to differentiate it from [[modelio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modelio), `[apple-modelio]` would have been a more accurate choice.

But Model I/O's name contains a space and a slash, to differentiate it from [Modelio](https://www.modelio.org). Tags do not support slashes. So I think `[model-io]` is the best we can do. If you don't think that's not enough, `[apple-model-io]` would be my second choice.

---

I tried to do this myself but [this old answer about tag renaming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) is no longer accurate and should be deleted.

Comment: I don't think the lower-scored of those answers was _ever_ correct.

Comment: I'm leaning toward `[apple-model-io]`, because the actual name _also_ has a space in it.

Comment: Are there guidelines on on tag names being different only by way of dashes? I can't think of similar examples.

Comment: I'm not sure of any official guidelines, but I'd say "don't." I think the system may also prevent the creation of such similar tags.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been done.

[scenekit-modelio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scenekit-modelio) has been renamed to [apple-model-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-model-io), and a synonym linking the two has been created for anyone who attempts to use the old name.